# Show a different set of checkboxes in a webform based on the value chosen in a combobox

Tags: javascript, html

Will a javascript library like Prototype/Scriptaculous or jQuery help me create a dynamic form on a webpage where I can show a different set of checkboxes based on the value chosen in a combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because all these libraries (*frameworks*) help make easy the cross-browser fiddling with the DOM..

Something along the lines of (in jQuery)

```
$(document).ready( //when the DOM is loaded invoke the following function
function(){
 $('combobox_selector').change( // when someone changes the value of the combobox invoke the following function
     function(){
                 $('some_checkbox_selector').hide(); // hide some checkboxes..
                 $('some_other_checkbox_selector').show(); // show some other checkboxes..
               }
  )
}
);
```

The *selector* parts of the code above should be replaced by the logic that determines which items gets hidden and which shown when the value of the combobox changes..

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can easily show/hide the desired checkbox-s in onChanged event of the combo box. You even don't need special JavaScript libraries to do that.